# Framework creation in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I would like to create a framework(Like coreData,CoreAudio,etc ) which can be used in multiple applications.

Can anyone post the links or tutorial for this ...

Answer (score 1):

Try Apple's [Framework Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html).

Note that sometimes shared code doesn't make sense in a framework. A lot of documentation about a framework assumes that you're going to install the framework on the computer, not embed it in the application.

Comment: Thanx John Calsbeek.I saw the documentation.Being new to the development, I am unable to proceed with that document.I like to have some steps kinda thing to do.